# Storing data to GlobalKTable

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am not able to understand how to save the data to globalKTable.
I tried creating the GlobalKTable in java  using

`GlobalKTable globalTable = builder.globalTable(inputTopic, Materialized.>as("global-store"));`

after this i am  not able to find any example which stores data to this GlobalKTable directly.
everywhere it is either used with joins or streams.

Answer (score 4):

Since each Stream application instance loads the whole `GlobalKTable` data, it disables logging to `changelog` topic by default, and the `GlobalKTable` uses the input topic as changelog source for restore process (to achieve fault tolerance) so it doesn't make sense to change the global store and you can't do that.

You can get read-only access to the global state in Processor API by using `ProcessorContext.getStateStore("global-store")` without the need to add the store to `Processor`.

One way you can achieve this is to push the updates you want to make to the `inputTopic` so it updates each GlobalKTable across all application instances.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not able to understand how to save the data to globalKTable. [...] i am not able to find any example which stores data to this GlobalKTable directly.

Today, you cannot directly write to a `GlobalKTable`.  You can only mutate a global table indirectly by writing events/records/messages to the topic from which the global table is populated from.